# jQuery Serialize order seems random

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, serialization

It seems to me that serialize in JQuery UI returns values not in the order that I see them.  As best I can tell, the array is in a random order, so I can't sort it in the order that I want.

The use case is a drag and drop table used to reorder.  After I drag a row, it reorders the table as expected.  However, once I drag, the serialize values seem to be random-ish.  So if I move something to item-2, I would expect it to be at 2.  However, sometimes it's at order 0, order 7, or order 10.  How can I capture and reorder the table and then pass those values into MySQL in the order expected?

Here's my javascript:

```
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
        var $originals = tr.children();
        var $helper = tr.clone();
        $helper.children().each(function(index) {
            $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
        });
        return $helper;
    },
    updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
        $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
            $(this).html(i + 1);
        });
    };

//noinspection JSUnresolvedFunction
$('#sortable').sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified,
    axis: 'y',
    opacity: 0.5,
    cursor: 'move',
    stop: updateIndex,
    update: saveRows
}).disableSelection();

function saveRows(){
    var tableRows = $(this).sortable('serialize');

    // POST to server using $.post or $.ajax
    //noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "/plugins/site/themes/admin/ajaxUpdate.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: tableRows
    });
}
```

And my php to update MYSQL:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/cfg.php");
foreach ($_POST['rowsort'] as $id => $order){

    $sql = "UPDATE `categories` SET `order` = :categoryorder WHERE `id` = :categoryid;";
    $stmt = mySQL::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':categoryorder', $order);
    $stmt->bindParam(':categoryid', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
```

My HTML is a bootstrap table which has `id="rowsort-<?php echo $i; ?>"`

I know that `serialize()` uses the id field by default, so I can't figure out why I can't get a consistent return value.

Comment: from your server , you have serialize before return success response

Comment: Not related to the question, but you only need to call `prepare()` and `bindParam()` once, not every time through the loop. Once you prepare and bind a statement, you can call `execute()` inside the loop to execute the same query repeatedly with different values of the variables.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that `execute()` could take parameters.  I'll definitely look into this. 

@Henrique-yc, I'm not great with Javascript and this is my first attempt at ajax.  Are you saying I need to define the serialize function as part of the $.ajax `success`?

Comment: No friend, im talking this action from your server side, but if youre using node js you have to make from there in node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barmar's answer was part of the solution, as was Henrique's comment. I definitely mixed the array up, but there was more to it on the javascript side and even more on the HTML side, which I completely botched:

This worked:

```
function saveRows(){
    var data = $('#sortable tr').map(function() { return {
        id: $(this).attr("rowsort") };
    });
    var tableRows = $(this).sortable('serialize');

    // POST to server using $.post or $.ajax
    //noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "/plugins/site/themes/admin/ajaxUpdate.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: tableRows
    });
}
```

The issue was that I needed to sort before serializing.  Once I did that, I got a lot closer, but it still wasn't right.  In my html, I was using `$i` as my id, but I already had a real id in the database.  Changing the javascript above and then using `id=rowsort-<?php echo category['id'];?>` was the real solution.

This question/experienced helped me a lot.  For anyone else that finds the sorting to be an issue in the future:

- Sort before serializing, not during.
- The ID in your HTML should be your database ID if you have one (and not a random or sequential, unrelated number)
- The `foreach` loop from your `$_POST` should list your sort order and then your actual ID in your database.

Comment: I don't see where you're sorting in the Javascript. What is the `data` variable for?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have `$id` and `$order` backwards in your `foreach` loop. The indexes of the parameters reflect their position in the sorted list, the values are the numbers in the `rowsort-<number>` ID. So it should be:

```
foreach ($_POST['rowsort'] as $order => $id) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  As best I can tell, it still seems to be random.  My $_POST data shows the index and then the order (nothing else), but when I pass that into the MySQL script, it doesn't seem to be in the order expected (and sometimes changes the wrong category).